# Is it possible to start a bash script in debug mode (bash -x) when using Slurm?

Tags: bash, debugging, slurm

When running a bash script on a local machine, one can use `bash -x script.sh` to run it in debug mode.

Is it possible with `sbatch script.sh` to specify a parameter in order to also run the script in debug mode on a cluster?

I couldn't find a hint for such a debug mode in the man pages for sbatch.

Comment: If you submit to SLURM the script `script.sh`, and that script uses `bash` as interpreter, just add `set -x` at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your sugesstion, Poshi, unfortunately it seems that one needs special permissions for this, as I'm getting this error message:
`slurmstepd: error: execve(): script.sh: Permission denied
srun: error: cluster: task 0: Exited with exit code 13`

Comment: And your script works when the `set -x` option is not there??? Can you show us your script?

Comment: Mysteriously it is working with the "set -x" option now! Why it didn't work with the same script previously I cannot say. But after logging out and logging in again the script runs without any errors. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user Poshi suggested, I added the option `set -x` to the beginning of my script and now the bash script is run in debug mode.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node 1
#SBATCH --mem=1GB
#SBATCH --partition normal
#SBATCH --time=00:01:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL,TIME_LIMIT

HELLO="hello there"
echo $HELLO
```

The slurm output file now looks like this:

```
cat *out
+ HELLO='hello there'
+ echo hello there
hello there
```